# JSFiddle returns "Please use POST request", but I'm not using a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

---

Hello all,

I was testing out a new method of hiding/showing tabs in JSFiddle, but for some reason it keeps returning "error: Please use POST request" any time I click a link.  Every other question pertaining to this error seems to have something to do with a form being submitted, but my fiddle is very, very simple and does not make use of a form in any way.  Why is the page not behaving as expected?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="#" id="videos-link">Videos</a><br>
    <a href="#" id="photos-link">Photos</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="home" class="page">Home page.</div>
<div id="videos" class="page">Videos page.</div>
<div id="photos" class="page">Photos page.</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#videos, #photos {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#videos-link').click(function () {
    $(".page").hide();
    $('#videos').show();
    return false
    });

$('#photos-link').click(function () {
    $(".page").hide();
    $('#photos').show();
    return false
    });
```

View fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zch0s04z/

**SOLVED**:  Apart from leaving out the "#" in the `href`, I also forgot to load the jQuery library.  I'll leave this question up to help out anyone as scatterbrained as myself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `#`-symbols in your links `href` attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="videos-link">Videos</a><br>
<a href="#" id="photos-link">Photos</a>
```

The above code will work with your fiddle:

```js
$('#videos-link').click(function () {
    $(".page").hide();
    $('#videos').show();
    return false
    });

$('#photos-link').click(function () {
    $(".page").hide();
    $('#photos').show();
    return false
    });
```

```css
#videos, #photos {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="#" id="videos-link">Videos</a><br>
    <a href="#" id="photos-link">Photos</a>
</div>
<br>
&mdash;
<br>
<div id="home" class="page">Home page.</div>
<div id="videos" class="page">Videos page.</div>
<div id="photos" class="page">Photos page.</div>
```

Comment: Edited.  Now I don't get the error, but the page still does not behave as expected.  Nothing happens when a link is clicked.

Comment: You'll have to include the jQuery library. On the left side under 'Frameworks & Extensions' select 'jQuery 2.1.3' from the dropdown. Edit: I included it in my snippet, run it and you'll see it works

Comment: Patrick2607 - I could swear I had included jQuery!  My bad.  Should I delete this question altogether?

Comment: No, that's not necessary, just leave it be. If other people have this problem, they could find this page and maybe this answer would be a solution to their problem too